# Cannot download Steam Console Client (SteamCMD)

Tags: software-installation

Cannot download Steam Console Client (SteamCMD) using "sudo apt install steamcmd" onto my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server. Got the instructions off the Valve Developer community site. Anyone know if this has been relocated or something?

Comment: `steamcmd:i386` version 0~20130205-1 is in the 18.04 multiverse repos as of 2/2/2020. I note it's `i386` even though my system is 64 bit, do you have multi-arch enabled?

Answer (score 2):

[steamcmd is in most recent Ubuntu releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steamcmd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Did you follow ***all*** the instructions? Notably...

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lib32gcc1 steamcmd
```